# Disable camera by default in Google Hangouts

Tags: google-hangouts

Is there a way to set it so my camera does not come on by default immediately when I place a call? When I click a contact in the new Hangouts popup in Chrome or in Gmail, I have a button that says Video Call. I used to be able to just do a voice call.

Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All newer implementations of Hangouts have a separate Voice and Video call button now.

[image]

Comment: looks like it is no longer like that

Answer (score 5):

I have a non-technological solution to this problem: I place a Post-It note on the back of the lid, and fold over enough of the non-sticky part of it over the bezel, up over the top of the lid, and on so that it covers the lens. Once I'm ready to be seen on-camera, I flip it over to reveal the lens.

Comment: Amazing! Just what I needed!

Answer (score 4):

You can install the [Hangremote Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/hangremote/naabbdmohmekdgecllphidjiaobnekcc), that allows to start OFF/ON mic/cam by default.

[image]

Simply turn on “No camera at start”.

It also allows you to fully control remote Hangouts.

[Hangremote](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/hangremote/naabbdmohmekdgecllphidjiaobnekcc) works for Desktop/Laptops(Chrome browser)

Comment: This is best software solution

Answer (score 1):

It's Simple!

Go to the settings -> Applications -> open Google meet -> permissions -> deny it for mic and camera

Thus you can change the permissions Allowed to the meet, i.e denying it will not open camera and microphone by default.
Please note whenever you want to give access to either of these, just click on the section under Google Meet app, it will ask for the one time permission and here you go.

Comment: Thanks, man. Your answer didn't exactly solve my problem but it does, however, gave me an idea which is kind of similar, so, kudos to you man. So,
what I did in my firefox: I opened up google meet & clicked the LOCK icon in the address bar & just removed the camera permission.

Comment: that's also a pretty cool trick to do so. The community will name it as a camera hack XD.

Comment: Apparently it does not work for going to next meeting, and the next... with mic/cam disabled by default